# Java varargs equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I have a function written in Java which accepts varargs as an argument. I wanted to port that function to C++. I tried to search but the closest I got is using std::vector of argument list. What would be the best way to convert varargs to C++? the function is as below.

```
public EventHandlerQueue<T> get (final EventHandler<T> ... handlers)
{
     // Do something with handlers
     return new EventHandlerQueue<T>(handlers)
}
```

Comment: [Variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates), or [variadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D).

Comment: @jweyrich: *variadic functions* are almost always a bad choice, and *variadic templates* are much more generic (and slightly harder to handle) than what the user needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I wanted to port that function to C++. I tried to search but the
>   closest I got is using std::vector of argument list.

Which is exactly correct, and exactly what the Java varags list actually is, just with some different syntax.

Answer (score 6):

`varargs` in Java is pure syntactic sugar. It get's translated by the compiler into a call to the function passing/receiving an *array of `EventHandler<T>`*.

The closest in C++11 would be `std::initializer_list<EventHandler<T>>` where you will need to encapsulate the arguments in an extra pair of curly braces:

```
EventHandlerQueue<T> get(std::initailizer_list<EventHandler<T>> handlers);

obj.get( {EventHandler1, EventHandler2} );
// asuming that `obj` is an object for which the above member is defined.
```

In C++03 there is no similar *syntactic sugar* and you will need to create an array/vector and pass it. Since arrays have statically defined sizes, the best option here is just passing a `std::vector<EventHandler<T> >`.

Comment: i'm not sure which is rightest of your answer and @DeadMg, so i upvoted both

Comment: @Alf: They are different alternatives, none of them need to be incorrect for the other to be right.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ these are 'variadic templates', as @chris says.

- http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=138
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates

Wikipedia's example:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printf(const char *s, T value, Args... args)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '%' && *(++s) != '%') {
            std::cout << value;
            ++s;
            printf(s, args...); // call even when *s == 0 to detect extra arguments
            return;
        }
        std::cout << *s++;
    }
    throw std::logic_error("extra arguments provided to printf");
}
```